# Deducing type of non-type template parameter based on value

Tags: c++, templates

When writing a function template, is it possible for the type of a non-type template parameter to be deduced based on the value provided for that parameter?

Visual Studio accepts this:

```
template<typename T, T Value> void foo(T x) {
    // some algorithm using x and Value goes here
}

void bar() {
    foo<int, -1>(42.0); // calls foo<T = int, Value = -1>(int)
}
```

But what I want to do is something like this (made-up syntax):

```
template<typename T Value> void foo(T x) {
    // some algorithm using x and Value goes here
}

void bar() {
    foo<-1>(42.0); // deduces the type of T from -1,
                   // calls foo<T = int, Value = -1>(int)
}
```

Is this possible (ie. not having to specify the type of `T` explicitly)?

Comment: @Xeo Aha! `template<auto X>` is a much better way of expressing the concept I'm after :)

Comment: Note that there is a proposal to allow something like this, via `template<using typename T; T X>`, where the `using` part means the type is deduced.